# Construct HTML Field?

Tags: java, html, multipart

I've been trying to go at this for a few hours now, and also searched the web, but simply can't find a solution.

I need to construct a Text Area (Whether it be JTextArea, JTextPane, or JEditorPane doesn't matter) which can read and format HTML.

I know that the JEditorPane can show HTML by giving it a Hyperlink, but what if I already got the HTML text, and just wants to show it..? If I use setText() it just shows a white field. Nothing in it.

The HTML text I get, is from an Email. I get it, using the following code (Just a snippet of it)

```
            String subject = message[row].getSubject();
            String from = InternetAddress.toString(message[row].getFrom());
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) message[row].getContent();
            for(int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                String disp = bp.getDisposition();
                if(disp != null && (disp.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT))) {
                    // Do something
                } else {
                    body.append(bp.getContent());
                }
            }
            EmailContent ec = new EmailContent(new JFrame(),true,from,subject,body.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Help?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: *"but what if I already got the HTML text, and just wants to show it..?"* What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Who minus voted me? Also, I tried reading that, and didn't really help. The JEditorPane is set to do text/html instead of text/plain. When I use setText(htmltext) it just gives me a blank JEditorPane. I even checked the string passed, and it's just fine. I don't get it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It just showed the HTML text. Nothing was formatted or actually shown as it was supposed to.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the content type or whether the `JEditorPane` is editable.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12504/discussion-between-vipar-and-andrew-thompson)

Comment: *"let us continue this discussion in chat"* No thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class HTMLFromString {

    HTMLFromString() {
        JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();

        String html = "<html><body><h1>Title</h1><p>Paragraph..";
        // Important!
        jep.setContentType("text/html");
        jep.setText(html);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jep);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new HTMLFromString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

This version creates some HTML using (mostly) your snippet (with some actual content), prefixed with `<html>` to produce a result.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class HTMLFromString {

    static String SNIPPET = 
            "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional" +
            "//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">" +
            "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>" +
            "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; " +
            "charset=Windows-1252\" /><title></title>" +
            "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
            "a, a:visited" +
            "{" +
            "  color: #406377;" +
            "}" +
            "</style>" + 
            "</head>" +
            "<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" style=\"background-color: #ffffff; " +
            "width: 600px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif; color: " +
            "#000; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px;\"><h1>Hi!</h1>";

    HTMLFromString() {
        JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();

        String html = "<html>" + SNIPPET;
        // Important!
        jep.setContentType("text/html");
        jep.setText(html);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jep);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new HTMLFromString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Only difference I can spot is, that it starts with the html tag, while mine doesn't. The HTML I get is extracted from an Email so it looks like this: (snippet) http://pastebin.com/Ls6w0A7b

Comment: Your's still has an `<HTML>` tag and therefore, is still valid HTML. The `<!DOCTYPE>` tag is a comment, specifying the versioning and type of HTML.

Comment: Is that just the start of the snippet?  It is not well-formed, as shown.  Yes the HTML formatting in Swing components requires the leading `<html>`.  The strings that will render as HTML in Swing do not need to be well-formed (the string in the above code was neither valid nor well-formed) but it is finicky about some things.

Comment: Yes that's just the start. I was wondering if I have to remove this part <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> or what?

Comment: Adding <html> to the line before parsing it seems to have fixed it a little. Thanks for that least. Please be less tempered next time <_<

Comment: *"Another question I never got an answer that solved the problem. What do you want me to do about it?"*  What I want is not that important (it is the impression it sends to other people, that is important).  What you might do is delete unanswered questions.  SO is specialized for questions with answers.  Questions that are unanswerable or unanswered after a long time are effectively noise. *"reformed the question"* Yes, I noted that.  But is was not much improved, and did not include an SSCCE.  Someone has balanced the down-vote with an up-vote, in any case.